# WinForms DragDrop path length limitation

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm using WinForms and have a DragDrop operation that handles a file being dragged onto the window. This works fine but if the path to the file is very long it just fails. `string[] fileList = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);` results in fileList being `null`.

Does anyone know what the limitation is or any way to work around it?

Thanks!

Update: The data in GetFormats is as follows:

Short Filename:

`Shell IDList Array
UsingDefaultDragImage
DragImageBits
DragContext
DragSourceHelperFlags
InShellDragLoop
FileDrop
FileNameW
FileName
IsShowingLayered
DragWindow
IsComputingImage
DropDescription
DisableDragText
ComputedDragImage
IsShowingText`

Long Filename:

`Shell IDList Array
UntrustedDragDrop
UsingDefaultDragImage
DragImageBits
DragContext
DragSourceHelperFlags
InShellDragLoop
FileDrop
FileNameW
FileName`

Comment: What do you get from `GetFormats()`?  Is it possible that the item you dragged is a shell object and not a real ordinary file on disk?  Paths only exist for disk files, other kinds of shell objects will be handled as PIDLs.

Comment: There are a whole lot of related formats documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx  `CFSTR_MOUNTEDVOLUME` ("similar to CF_HDROP, but it contains only a single path and can handle the longer path strings that might be needed to represent a path when the volume is mounted on a folder") and `CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST` ("used in much the same way as CF_HDROP, but it contains PIDLs instead of file system paths. Using PIDLs allows the CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST format to handle virtual objects as well as file system objects") sound relevant

Comment: The object being dropped is a file. The file lives in a folder on my desktop and works perfectly until I change the name of the folder to a very long name, at which point this occurs. Changing the folder back to a sensible length name makes the problem go away.

Comment: Solving it still requires knowing what you get from `GetFormats()`

Comment: In both cases GetFormats contains a number of things, among them FileDrop.

Comment: Argh I hate how you can't put newlines in comments. I will add the lists of what is seen in GetFormats to the actual question.

Comment: Also, I presume you've tested [`GetFileDropList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.getfiledroplist(v=vs.110).aspx) and it behaves the same way?

Comment: I can't see that member anywhere on the DragEventArgs

Comment: Oh I see, difference between `DataObject` class, which is the documentation I was looking at, and `IDataObject` interface, which is what `e.Data` is.

Comment: OK interestingly if I cast e.Data to that class and call `GetFileDropList` I do get the filename, in Windows95 style: `C:\Users\someguy\Desktop\THISIS~1\Archive\SINGMA~1\LogFiles\FIX-FI~1\222000.fel`

Comment: Well let's see if we can't figure out what that function does differently from the code in your question, shall we?  It's [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataObject.cs,341)   Looks same as yours except that it passes `true` as the argument to allow conversion.

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately the code following on from that won't load from the file when it's named in that format... I'll have to see if I can get it to turn that into a 'real' filename. That's a job for tomorrow as I have to go now, but thanks for the help!

Comment: [GetLongPathName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980(v=vs.85).aspx) -- not sure if there's already a C# wrapper or you will need to pinvoke.

Comment: The PInvoke did work to get the 'real' filename as it appears to the user, however it looks like the rest of .NET has limitiations, so whether you use the compacted name or the expanded name, things like `File.Exists(path)` and `new FileStream(path)` will fail as well. Basically it looks like the long filename support is only half baked, at least when using Win7 and .NET 2.0. Pretty funny really - like it should say on the box "Requires 8,000,000,000 bytes of RAM. Filenames limited to 256 bytes". :-) Thanks heaps for your help in discovering the cause though.

Comment: There are a couple tricks you can pull, let's see if I can find you a guide to long path support in .NET.  Otherwise, you can always p/invoke -- Unicode versions of file functions allow use to use a prefix of `\\?` to bypass canonicalization, which is where the length limit you're likely to actually hit lies (there still is a limit, but it's 32000 characters and some, so not a problem in practice)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt762843(v=vs.110).aspx and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/ may be helpful

Comment: I read up on that, but according to what I was reading it still won't work with standard functions like `File.Exists`.

Comment: Oh I see, since .NET 4.6.2 it's supported. Unfortunately since people are using this program on XP/2000/Vista age machines I can't switch to that.

Comment: No, but using the manifest you can have the long path support enabled when running on 4.6.2, while still targeting the lowest common framework (4.5 I guess)